# Finding the value for this integral

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

While solving some exercises on orthnormal set on Hilbert spaces, I tried to solve the following problem:
Let $\left\{ f_{1},f_{2},...,f_{9}\right\} $ be an orthonormal set in $L^{2}
\left[ 0,1\right] .$ Assume that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}6xf_{1}\left( x\right) dx=2 
$$
and
$$
\int_{0}^{1}6xf_{2}\left( x\right) dx=2\sqrt{2}.
$$
What can you say about the value of $\int_{0}^{1}6xf_{5}\left( x\right) dx?$
Give reasons.

I tried to write the function $6x$ as a linear combination of this orthonormal set and made use of the given values but in vain. Any help with that is very appreciated.

Comment: HInt - what is the $L^2$ norm squared of $x$?

Comment: Yes, the usual space of square-integrable functions

Comment: my question was meant to be a leading question (a hint!) - what is the numerical value of    $\int^1_0 \, x^2 \, dx$ ? then compare with the other givens...

Comment: The value is 1/3. Could you give me some more details about your idea, please?

Comment: If $v = a_1e_1 + a_2 e_2 +\cdots + a_n e_n$, in an i.p v.s. $V, (\cdot,\cdot)$, with $e_i$ orthonormal, 1) what is another expression for $a_i$?  2) what is an equation for $|v|^2$ in terms of the $a_i$? (This is still only a hint - but I hope it helps)

Comment: $a_{i}=\left( v,e_{i}\right) $ and $\left\Vert v\right\Vert
^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\vert a_{i}\right\vert ^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\vert
\left( v,e_{i}\right) \right\vert ^{2}$

Comment: So apply that with  the vector $v$ the function $v(x) = 6x$ [or $v(x)= x$, as I had said because I had thought the math a bit easier for me - but it's not ], and calculate $|a_i|^2$  with $e_i= f_i$, for $i=1,2$.

Comment: @peterag I calculated $\left\vert a_{1}\right\vert ^{2}$ and $\left\vert
a_{2}\right\vert ^{2}$, but now what about the requested $\left\vert
a_{5}\right\vert ^{2}?$

Comment: write down the three numbers $|v|^2$, $|a_1|^2$, $|a_2|^2$ (do so here, please). Do you not see a relationship?

Comment: @peterag $\left\Vert v\right\Vert ^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\left( 6x\right)
^{2}dx=12,$ $\left\vert a_{1}\right\vert ^{2}=\left( 2\right)
^{2}=4$ and $\left\vert a_{2}\right\vert ^{2}=\left( 2\sqrt{2}\right) ^{2}=8$

Comment: and the relationship between those numbers?

Comment: @peterag they are equal. Do you mean that the requested formula will equal to zero?

Comment: you wrote "they are equal"? I assume that you mean $12 = 4 +8$... but yes that means that the only way to add any other positive numbers  on the rhs of the equality $12 = 4 +8$ is with positive numbers equal to zero. Please note that a priori, you do not know that $v$ is in the linear span of your $f_i$ (in fact of your $f_1$ and $f_2$), although the constraints do imply so after the fact.    In general one has $$|v|^2 \ge |a_1|^2 + \cdots + |a_n|^2,$$which is good enough (equality holds iff $v$ is in the span of $f_i$).

Comment: signing off!!! good luck

Comment: @peterag Really really thanks for your valuable and detailed comment